# How to add customise dialogue box in the graph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

[image]Is it possible to add a dialogue box(may be annotation) in a graph with custom tick design
which show the highest point in the graph with its y-axis value. If yes how??

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You should be able to do this after the chart draws using [public API methods](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html): numRows() and getValue() to find the max, toDomCoords() to convert to DOM coordinates for your overlay.